# Using select() for non-blocking sockets

Tags: c, sockets, select, bsd

I am trying to use the select function to have non-blocking i/o between a server and 1 client (no more) where the communication flows nicely (can send at any time and the other will receive without waiting to send). I found a tutorial with some code and tried to adapt it to mine. This is what I have -

Server

```
#define PORT "4950"
#define STDIN 0

struct sockaddr name;

void set_nonblock(int socket) {
    int flags;
    flags = fcntl(socket,F_GETFL,0);
    assert(flags != -1);
    fcntl(socket, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
}


// get sockaddr, IPv4 or IPv6:
void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa) {
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET)
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);

    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

int main(int agrc, char** argv) {
    int status, sock, adrlen, new_sd;

    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *servinfo;  //will point to the results

    //store the connecting address and size
    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr;
    socklen_t their_addr_size;

    fd_set read_flags,write_flags; // the flag sets to be used
    struct timeval waitd;          // the max wait time for an event
    int sel;                      // holds return value for select();

    //socket infoS
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints); //make sure the struct is empty
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; //tcp
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;     //use local-host address

    //get server info, put into servinfo
    if ((status = getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo error: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
        exit(1);
    }

    //make socket
    sock = socket(servinfo->ai_family, servinfo->ai_socktype, servinfo->ai_protocol);
    if (sock < 0) {
        printf("\nserver socket failure %m", errno);
        exit(1);
    }

    //allow reuse of port
    int yes=1;
    if (setsockopt(sock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&yes,sizeof(int)) == -1) {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(1);
    }

    //unlink and bind
    unlink("127.0.0.1");
    if(bind (sock, servinfo->ai_addr, servinfo->ai_addrlen) < 0) {
        printf("\nBind error %m", errno);
        exit(1);
    }

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

    //listen
    if(listen(sock, 5) < 0) {
        printf("\nListen error %m", errno);
        exit(1);
    }
    their_addr_size = sizeof(their_addr);

    //accept
    new_sd = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&their_addr, &their_addr_size);
    if( new_sd < 0) {
        printf("\nAccept error %m", errno);
        exit(1);
    }

    set_nonblock(new_sd);
    cout<<"\nSuccessful Connection!";

    char* in = new char[255];
    char* out = new char[255];
    int numSent;
    int numRead;


    while(1) {

        waitd.tv_sec = 10;
        FD_ZERO(&read_flags);
        FD_ZERO(&write_flags);
        FD_SET(new_sd, &read_flags);

        if(strlen(out) != 0)
            FD_SET(new_sd, &write_flags);

        sel = select(new_sd+1, &read_flags, &write_flags, (fd_set*)0, &waitd);
        if(sel < 0)
            continue;

        //socket ready for reading
        if(FD_ISSET(new_sd, &read_flags)) {
            FD_CLR(new_sd, &read_flags);

            memset(&in, 0, sizeof(in));

            if(recv(new_sd, in, sizeof(in), 0) <= 0) {
                close(new_sd);
                break;
            }
            else
                cout<<"\n"<<in;
        }   //end if ready for read

        //socket ready for writing
        if(FD_ISSET(new_sd, &write_flags)) {

            FD_CLR(new_sd, &write_flags);
            send(new_sd, out, strlen(out), 0);
            memset(&out, 0, sizeof(out));
        }
    }   //end while

    cout<<"\n\nExiting normally\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Client (basically the same just minus an accept call) -

```
#define PORT "4950"

struct sockaddr name;

void set_nonblock(int socket) {
    int flags;
    flags = fcntl(socket,F_GETFL,0);
    assert(flags != -1);
    fcntl(socket, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
}

// get sockaddr, IPv4 or IPv6:
void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa) {
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET)
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);

    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

int main(int agrc, char** argv) {
    int status, sock, adrlen;

    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *servinfo;  //will point to the results

    fd_set read_flags,write_flags; // the flag sets to be used
    struct timeval waitd;          // the max wait time for an event
    int sel;                      // holds return value for select();

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints); //make sure the struct is empty
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; //tcp
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;     //use local-host address

    //get server info, put into servinfo
    if ((status = getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo error: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
        exit(1);
    }

    //make socket
    sock = socket(servinfo->ai_family, servinfo->ai_socktype, servinfo->ai_protocol);
    if (sock < 0) {
        printf("\nserver socket failure %m", errno);
        exit(1);
    }

    if(connect(sock, servinfo->ai_addr, servinfo->ai_addrlen) < 0) {
        printf("\nclient connection failure %m", errno);
        exit(1);
    }

    cout<<"\nSuccessful connection!";

    set_nonblock(sock);

    char* out = new char[255];
    char* in = new char[255];
    int numRead;
    int numSent;

    while(1) {

        waitd.tv_sec = 10;
        FD_ZERO(&read_flags);
        FD_ZERO(&write_flags);
        FD_SET(sock, &read_flags);

        if(strlen(out) != 0)
            FD_SET(sock, &write_flags);


        sel = select(sock+1, &read_flags, &write_flags, (fd_set*)0, &waitd);
        if(sel < 0)
            continue;

        //socket ready for reading
        if(FD_ISSET(sock, &read_flags)) {
            FD_CLR(sock, &read_flags);

            memset(&in, 0, sizeof(in));

            if(recv(sock, in, sizeof(in), 0) <= 0) {
                close(sock);
                break;
            }
            else
                cout<<"\n"<<in;
        }   //end if ready for read

        //socket ready for writing
        if(FD_ISSET(sock, &write_flags)) {
            FD_CLR(sock, &write_flags);
            send(sock, out, strlen(out), 0);
            memset(&out, 0, sizeof(out));
        }
    }   //end while

    cout<<"\n\nExiting normally\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that when I run them, nothing happens. I can type into one and hit enter and nothing shows up on the other screen (and vice versa). Thats not a whole of information for me to debug and this is my first real attempt at using select so I thought maybe I am just unaware of something simple. If anything can be spotted as wrong or weird please point it out, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the program working correctly now.

server -

```
#define PORT "4950"
#define STDIN 0

struct sockaddr name;

void set_nonblock(int socket) {
    int flags;
    flags = fcntl(socket,F_GETFL,0);
    assert(flags != -1);
    fcntl(socket, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
}


// get sockaddr, IPv4 or IPv6:
void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa) {
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET)
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);

    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}


int main(int agrc, char** argv) {
    int status, sock, adrlen, new_sd;

    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *servinfo;  //will point to the results

    //store the connecting address and size
    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr;
    socklen_t their_addr_size;

    fd_set read_flags,write_flags; // the flag sets to be used
    struct timeval waitd = {10, 0};          // the max wait time for an event
    int sel;                      // holds return value for select();


    //socket infoS
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints); //make sure the struct is empty
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; //tcp
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;     //use local-host address

    //get server info, put into servinfo
    if ((status = getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo error: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
        exit(1);
    }

    //make socket
    sock = socket(servinfo->ai_family, servinfo->ai_socktype, servinfo->ai_protocol);
    if (sock < 0) {
        printf("\nserver socket failure %m", errno);
        exit(1);
    }

    //allow reuse of port
    int yes=1;
    if (setsockopt(sock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&yes,sizeof(int)) == -1) {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(1);
    }

    //unlink and bind
    unlink("127.0.0.1");
    if(bind (sock, servinfo->ai_addr, servinfo->ai_addrlen) < 0) {
        printf("\nBind error %m", errno);
        exit(1);
    }

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

    //listen
    if(listen(sock, 5) < 0) {
        printf("\nListen error %m", errno);
        exit(1);
    }
    their_addr_size = sizeof(their_addr);

    //accept
    new_sd = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&their_addr, &their_addr_size);
    if( new_sd < 0) {
        printf("\nAccept error %m", errno);
        exit(1);
    }

    //set non blocking
    set_nonblock(new_sd);
    cout<<"\nSuccessful Connection!\n";

    char in[255];
    char out[255];
    memset(&in, 0, 255);
    memset(&out, 0, 255);
    int numSent;
    int numRead;

    while(1) {

        FD_ZERO(&read_flags);
        FD_ZERO(&write_flags);
        FD_SET(new_sd, &read_flags);
        FD_SET(new_sd, &write_flags);
        FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &read_flags);
        FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &write_flags);

        sel = select(new_sd+1, &read_flags, &write_flags, (fd_set*)0, &waitd);

        //if an error with select
        if(sel < 0)
            continue;

        //socket ready for reading
        if(FD_ISSET(new_sd, &read_flags)) {

            //clear set
            FD_CLR(new_sd, &read_flags);

            memset(&in, 0, 255);

            numRead = recv(new_sd, in, 255, 0);
            if(numRead <= 0) {
                printf("\nClosing socket");
                close(new_sd);
                break;
            }
            else if(in[0] != '\0')
                cout<<"\nClient: "<<in;

        }   //end if ready for read

        //if stdin is ready to be read
        if(FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &read_flags))
            fgets(out, 255, stdin);


        //socket ready for writing
        if(FD_ISSET(new_sd, &write_flags)) {
            //printf("\nSocket ready for write");
            FD_CLR(new_sd, &write_flags);
            send(new_sd, out, 255, 0);
            memset(&out, 0, 255);
        }   //end if
    }   //end while

   cout<<"\n\nExiting normally\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The client is basically the same...only difference really is the lack of listen and accept.

Comment: *"I'm too tired to explain it, so I'll just post the code to compare with the above code if anyone in the future needs the info"* that's not the way to write a helpful answer -1

Comment: In this section:
        
        `FD_SET(new_sd, &read_flags);
        FD_SET(new_sd, &write_flags);
        FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &read_flags);
        FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &write_flags);` 

The first 2 FD_SETs are overridden by the 2nd two. Why bother?

Comment: @EntangledLoops I disagree - these four lines will add new_sd and STDIN_FILENO to the sets read_flags and write_flags. From [fd_set man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fd_set):  _FD_SET() and FD_CLR() respectively add and remove a given file  descriptor from a set._

Comment: @pepan You're obviously correct as I look at it now; don't remember what I was thinking when it read it in October. +1 for a well-bodied example

Answer (score 15):

> The problem is that when I run them, nothing happens.

The real problem is that people have been pasting stuff from Beej for years without understanding it. That's why I don't really like that guide; it gives large blocks of code without really explaining them in detail.

You're not reading anything and not sending anything; no fgets, scanf, cin, etc. Here's what I would do:

```
FD_SET(sock, &read_flags);
FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &read_flags);

/* .. snip .. */

if(FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &read_flags)) {
    fgets(out, len, stdin);
}
```

This will monitor `stdin` and read from it when input is available; then, when the socket is writeable (`FD_ISSET(sock, &write_flags)`), it will send the buffer.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes, I have been reading Beej's tutorial for the last few days and am barely getting by. I tried adding that to my code, but now I get a segmentation fault whenever I type something into either terminal on that terminal (type 'hi' into server, server seg faults, client closes fine, vice versa). I tried getline to make sure it wasn't just fgets. GDB doesn't really help - tells me the backtrace is just #0  0x08048c93 in main (). Sorry to ask (little desperate at this point), but do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: @Sterling compile using `-g`. Also, for starters declare `out` and `in` like so:  `char out[255];`.

Comment: weird...when I just change those declarations the program doesn't seg fault, but it goes straight through the while loop and exits.

Comment: @Sterling Try to debug it. Add `printf` lines if you need to. Add a printf line right after the "select" `printf("Select fired\n");` etc.

Comment: Will do. Another weird thing maybe worth noting...select fires a different number of times for the two programs and a different number of times each time I run it. Sometimes 10, sometimes 20, sometimes 5, then closes the socket. Somehow the recv call is <= 0 without me inputting anything...also doesn't change when I leave the sockets as blocking.

Comment: Sure, he doesn't use `fgets`, `cin`, etc., but he does call `recv`. Why would that be insufficient?

Comment: A more informative tutorial I found:                                                                    http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_i5_54/rzab6/xnonblock.htm

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add that above example may not work as expected on Linux. On Linux waitd may be modified by select. So for Linux, waitd should be rewritten before select.

See the "timeout" section in the man page for select.

Comment: Would not this be better placed as a comment on the accepted answer?