# How can I make my server multithreaded?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, client-server, server-side

I have a WinSock server and I was wondering how to make it multi-threaded. I have used threads before and I understand what they do. But I'm not sure how to use them with my server code. So here it is:

main.cpp

```
/* This is our Server */

//Includes
#include "Functions.h"

//Main function
int main(){
    DLLVERSION = MAKEWORD(2,1);
    answer = WSAStartup(DLLVERSION, &wsaData);
    sConnect = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(HostIP);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    sListen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
    bind(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    listen(sListen, SOMAXCONN);

    //Listening for clients
    for(;;){
        Print("Waiting for incoming connections");
        //If a connection is found
        if(sConnect = accept(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &addrlen)){
            Print("Connection found!");
            Send("Hello!");
        }
    }
}
```

How would I make this server multithreaded?

I tried using `CreateThread();` but as soon as another thread is created, the last thread ends for some reason. Can anyone help?

Comment: its not necessary to write a server that handles multiple request with threads. You could use `select()`. Is this a requeriment?

Comment: @Sebastian I am coding a game server, is it necessary to do so with a game server?

Comment: It's not theoretically necessary, but practically yes. BTW it's probably not a good idea to have one thread per request either. Look into threadpools.

Comment: @MSalters What do you recommend i do for a game server? Because since it's going to have multiple players online at once, don't i need to be accepting connections like every millisecond?

Comment: @user2635579: Not really. A typical game takes thousands of milliseconds to load. Just send the connection request early, and your users won't notice even if the accept took half a second.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select` (or `poll` too if you are on POSIX land) to wait on the server socket.

select: [Using select() for non-blocking sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715736/using-select-for-non-blocking-sockets)

You main server process listens on the socket and as soon as a request comes in you spin off a thread (from a thread pool) which interacts with the client. That's the gist of it. Windows has a thread pool to use, take a look at the `QueueUserWorkItem` Win 32 call http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684957%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: The question suggests Windows (retagged)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a few things:

- Sockets are text streams, but you probably uses messages. You probably want a few threads which each listen to a number of sockets. When they do have a message, dispatch that message, generally to another thread.
- In Windows, you'd use `WSAWaitForMultipleObjects()` to listen to multiple sockets.
- You indeed want a thread to deal with new incoming connections. One should be enough. Each new connection should be sent to added to one of those listener threads.
- Welcome messages can be sent by the listener thread as it picks up the incoming connection.
- You can use a semaphore to keep track of the number of incoming connections not yet picked up by listening threads. Add the semaphore to `WSAWaitForMultipleObjects`, and the first idle listening thread will pick up the incoming connection. This balances the load across threads.

Comment: + on Windows he can have a ready to go thread pool if he uses the `QueueUserWorkItem` Win 32 API http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684957%28v=vs.85%29.aspx