# Select blocked using socket in c

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, select, chat

The code below is a chatroom. First I run the server, and then the clients. The clients reach the server with sockets. Then the server accepts the connection and the client has to enter his nickname.
I use threads because this way, the fgets is not blocking and multiple clients can reach the server even if a client is slow to enter his nickname.
Until here, there is no problem and everything works, even the select.

After this, the client can introduce a message which is send to all the clients (this is the principle of a chat :P). The problem is that from here, the select doesn't react and stay blocked. Maybe it's because of the FD_set or the threads but actually I don't know and that is the problem.

server.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <pthread.h>


#define MYPORT 5555
#define PSEUDO_MAX 30
#define MESSAGE_MAX 1000

#define BACKLOG 10



struct User {
  char pseudo[PSEUDO_MAX];
  int socket;
  struct User *next;
};

struct Thread {
  struct User* lst;
  fd_set* readfds;
  int* max;
  int socket;
  pthread_mutex_t* mutex;
};

void add(struct User** pp, const char *t, const int sock)
{
    struct User *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
    strcpy(p->pseudo, t);
    p->socket = sock;
    p->next = NULL;

    while (*pp)
        pp = &(*pp)->next;
    *pp = p;
}

void print(const struct User* n) 
{
    for ( ; n; n = n->next ){
        printf("LISTE : %s\n", n->pseudo);
        printf("LISTE : %d\n", n->socket);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void *thread_pseudo(void *arg)
{
  struct Thread* ps_thread = (struct Thread*)arg;
  int nsock = ps_thread->socket;
  struct User* lst = ps_thread->lst;
  int* max = ps_thread->max;
  pthread_mutex_t* mutex = ps_thread->mutex;
  pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
  fd_set* readfds = ps_thread->readfds;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);

    char pseudo[PSEUDO_MAX];
    if (send(nsock, "Bienvenue sur le chat !\n",24,0)==-1){
      perror("Serveur: send");
    }

    if (recv(nsock, pseudo, PSEUDO_MAX, 0) == -1) {
      perror("Serveur: recv 2: ");
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);

    FD_SET(nsock, readfds); // Ajout du nouveau socket au select
    *max = (nsock < *max ? *max : nsock);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);

    add(&lst, pseudo, nsock);
    print(lst);



    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int findSender(fd_set* readfds, const struct User* n){
  int socket = 0;
  for ( ; n; n = n->next ){
    if(FD_ISSET(n->socket, readfds)){
      socket = n->socket;
    }
  }
  return socket;
}

int main()
{
  pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;


  int sockfd2, new_fd;  // listen on sock_fd, new connection on new_fd
  int max;
  struct sockaddr_in my_addr;  // my address information
  struct sockaddr_in their_addr; // connector's address information
  unsigned int sin_size;
  int yes=1;
  struct User *lst = NULL; // Initialisation de la liste des Users
  struct Thread *ps_thread = malloc(sizeof(*ps_thread)); // Initialisation du struct qui contient les paramètres pour le thread
  fd_set readfds;


  if ((sockfd2 = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("Serveur: socket 2");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  if (setsockopt(sockfd2,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR, &yes,sizeof(int)) == -1) {
    perror("Serveur: setsockopt 2");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;        
  my_addr.sin_port = htons(MYPORT);   
  my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  memset(&(my_addr.sin_zero), '\0', 8);

  if (bind(sockfd2, (struct sockaddr *)&my_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) {
    perror("Serveur: bind 2");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  if (listen(sockfd2, BACKLOG) == -1) {
    perror("Serveur: listen 2");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  //Initialisation du fd_set et du max    
  FD_ZERO(&readfds);
  FD_SET(sockfd2, &readfds);
  max = sockfd2;



  while(1){
    if (select(max+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL) < 0){
      printf("error select\n");
    }

    int sock = findSender(&readfds, lst);

    if(FD_ISSET(sockfd2, &readfds)){
      new_fd = accept(sockfd2, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);

      if (new_fd == -1) { 
      perror("Serveur: accept");
      }

      pthread_t thread; 
      ps_thread->lst = lst;
      ps_thread->readfds = &readfds;
      ps_thread->max = &max;
      ps_thread->socket = new_fd;
      ps_thread->mutex = &mutex;

      if (pthread_create(&thread, NULL, thread_pseudo, ps_thread)) {
      perror("pthread_create");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
    }

    else if(FD_ISSET(sock, &readfds)) {
      char* message;
      int sock = findSender(&readfds, lst);
      if (recv(sock, message, MESSAGE_MAX, 0) == -1) {
        perror("Serveur: recv 2: ");
      }
    }

    else{
      printf("ERROR\n");
    }
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define PORT 5555
#define PSEUDO_MAX 30
#define MESSAGE_MAX 1000


void getPseudo(char* pseudo) {
  size_t ln = -1;
  while (ln <= 0 || ln > PSEUDO_MAX-1) {
    printf("Entrez votre pseudo : ");
    fgets(pseudo, PSEUDO_MAX, stdin);
    ln = strlen(pseudo) - 1;
  }

  if (pseudo[ln] == '\n')
    pseudo[ln] = '\0';
}

void getMessage(char* message) {
  size_t ln = -1;
  while (ln <= 0 || ln > MESSAGE_MAX-1) {
    printf(">");
    fgets(message, MESSAGE_MAX, stdin);
    ln = strlen(message) - 1;
  }

  if (message[ln] == '\n')
    message[ln] = '\0';
}

void *thread_message(void *arg)
{
  printf("Bonjour\n");
  char* message;
  message = malloc (sizeof(char) * MESSAGE_MAX);
  int* sockfd = (int*)arg;
  printf("%d\n", *sockfd);

  while (1) {
    getMessage(message);
    if (send(*sockfd, message, strlen(message), 0) == -1){
      perror("Client: send message");
    }
  }
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int sockfd, numbytes;  
  struct sockaddr_in their_addr;
         // connector's address information 
  struct hostent *he;
  char buf[MESSAGE_MAX];
  long int term1, term2, res;
  int demande_pseudo = 0;
  char* pseudo;
  pseudo = malloc (sizeof(char) * PSEUDO_MAX);

  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Donner le nom du serveur.");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  if ((he=gethostbyname(argv[1])) == NULL) {
    perror("Client: gethostbyname");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  if ((sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("Client: socket");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }





  their_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;    
  their_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
  their_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr*)he->h_addr);
  memset(&(their_addr.sin_zero), '\0', 8); 

  if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) {
    perror("Client: connect");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  while (1) { 
    if ((numbytes=recv(sockfd, buf, MESSAGE_MAX-1, 0)) == -1) {
      perror("Client: recv");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (demande_pseudo == 0) {
      buf[numbytes] = '\0';
      printf("%s",buf);
      getPseudo(pseudo);
      printf("Tu as choisi comme pseudo : %s\n", pseudo);
      demande_pseudo++;
      printf("%d\n", sockfd);
      if (send(sockfd, pseudo, strlen(pseudo), 0) == -1){
        perror("Client: send pseudo");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }

      pthread_t thread; 

      if (pthread_create(&thread, NULL, thread_message, &sockfd)) {
        perror("pthread_create");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
    }

    else
    {

    }

  }

  close(sockfd);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your question is confusing, try to be more specific giving some examples.
If I understood your question, your problem is that your **select** is configured to operate on blocking mode.
This is an example on how to set your socket flags to non-blocking mode.

```
flags = fcntl(sock, F_GETFL, 0);
if(flags < 0)
    err(1, "%s: fcntl", __FUNCTION__);

ret = fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
if(ret < 0)
    err(1, "%s: fcntl:", __FUNCTION__);
```

## Answer Update

Well, one of your problems is that your main function doesn't wait your thread update `readfds` and `max`, thus getting blocked on select with the wrong values for those variables. You could solve that by either adding `pthread_join(thread, NULL);` after you create your thread **OR** , as I said first, setting your select as non-blocking mode.

- With the second method(non-blocking mode) there will be times you
  have nothing to process from select so you need to handle this and not crash. **I would use that.**
- Using the first method (`pthread_join`) you'll not be able to process incoming
  requests while waiting for your thread to finish,hence invalidating  the whole purpose of having threads: being available to process incoming requests.

Try to develop those ideas and you'll make that code work! (:

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just changed my post, I hope it will be clearer.

Comment: Much better question now. Did some updates to my answer. Please, evaluate it :)

Comment: Thanks ! I understand your advice but how exactly do you make a select as non-blocking ? With the default and case stuff ? Or with the timeout ?

And an other question : after a select, do I have to add again all the sockets with FD_set(sock,readfds) or the previous sockets are still there ?

Comment: You're my hero @Felipe T. Bortolon ! :)

Comment: For non-blocking you can just set the socket as non-blocking just as it is in my answer (or check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715736/using-select-for-non-blocking-sockets) out). If you rather using timeout, just consult man pages. It is easier than explaining.
I guess you've already solved your problem, but I'm answering the first question for completude. :)